# pixel error with overflow: hidden and transform: translate

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, webkit, css-transitions

I have a box with a caption, which is `position: absolute` and hidden with `top: 100%`. The parent of the caption has `overflow: hidden`. When I hover the box, the caption slides up so it is fully visible.

The problem now is that during this transition, there is a pixel bug. That means the caption during the transition is 1 pixel less wide then the parent box. After the transition everything looks good.

It appears in IE 11 on Windows 8.1 and in Webkit browsers on Mac 10.11.2.

You should see this effect in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u46t0L31/2/). 
When you don't see the pixel bug, then try to resize the window.

You also see the error on the screenshot.

[image]

I have already tried to:

- Set the caption 1 pixel wider
- Add `overflow-x: hidden`
- Add `translate3d`

Comment: actually i can't see the error, could you take couple of screenshots of this pixel bug?

Comment: I'm not seeing it (Chrome / Mac 10.11.2) - Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @RyanLittle i've uploaded a screenshot. The screenshot is made in ie, but it looks like this in the other browsers.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this error before. the pixel bug is caused by the transform:translate.

try this on the parent element.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll give it a try using one of this options:

position: relative;

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);

-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; or webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

Comment: Can't replicate in the current machine I'm on. If I find some time this evening I'll try to from some other machine.

Comment: you should not use font-smoothing this is not standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth